# How do I fix the Laravel page not found error?

Tags: laravel

After registering, it redirects to / home. But I get a 404 error. When I set the route to / home, I get 302 continuous routing errors.

*RegisterController.php*

```php
use RegistersUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

*Route.php*

```php
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

*HomeController*

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can show your HomeController code?

Comment: Uptated my post.

Answer (score 0):

if you have in your `HomeController`'s construct a middleware that requires the user to be logged in then what you are getting is normal.

You should have a login page wich use the "guest" middleware.

or

login the user automatically once he registers before redirecting him to your `home` route.

```
Auth::login($user)
//or
Auth::loginUsingId($userId);
```

Comment: @Dodiş have you tried removing the middleware from your HomeController ?

Comment: When I remove the __construct function, when I try to access the / login page, it redirects back to the /home url and 404 page error.

Comment: that means that you are logged in. When trying to access /login, it redirects you to `/` or `/home` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** guest middleware.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
```

Your **HomeController** should look like

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

your **route.php** Look like

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**RegisterController** should look like

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

make sure you're following laravel authentication.

Comment: Okay, When I remove the __construct function, when I try to access the / login page, it redirects back to the /home url and 404 page error.

Comment: Because of there is no route of `/home` in yout route.php add route `home` in your route.php file